# How to change the weight of error bars in the y direction

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying, in Excel 2016, to show the change in shape of the histogram for the binomial distribution as n increases. Part of my code requires creating a scatter plot with very wide error bars, as suggested here http://thydzik.com/histogram-with-normal-distribution-overlay-in-excel/
so that I can get a smooth histogram on top of its histogram.

The problem is that I can't modify the weight of the error bars in the y direction. I recorded a macro of the creation process, but when I execute the macro it modifies the x error bars instead.

```
Sub Macro8()

    Range("F15:G25").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$F$15:$G$25")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementErrorBarStandardError)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 20
    End With
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlNoCap
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:= _
        xlMinusValues, Type:=xlPercent, Amount:=100
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 23.75
    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Smoothed Histogram"

End Sub
```

You can see the expected outcome vs the actual outcome, and the data (which will change for different cases, hence the need to modify the weight)

[image]

What should I add to the code to force it to work with the y error bars?

Comment: I tried looking in the office help, but they seem to believe the default setting is to affect the y error bars, except it doesn't happen that way. Anyone knows how I could actually contact their developers? I'm starting to believe it's actually a bug =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro recorder is not always your friend, and the VBA object model around error bars is incomplete. However, if all you need is to format Y error bars, then the following code will do you well enough.

```
Sub FatVerticalErrorBars()
    Range("F15:G25").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$F$15:$G$25")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:= _
        xlMinusValues, Type:=xlPercent, Amount:=100
    With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars
        .EndStyle = xlNoCap
        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 23.75
        End With
    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Smoothed Histogram"
End Sub
```